# How to change column name to weekday in Python

Tags: python, pandas

In python I have a column name on Pandas:

Example

```
country/Region 1/22/19  1/23/19  1/24/19  1/25/19  1/26/19
```

how can I change date to weekday

```
country/Region Tue   Wed       Thu     Fri       Sat
```

*It have a lot of column than Example

Comment: Question not clear, can you add a little context to it

Comment: Are you talking about a Pandas series?

Comment: Where are these columns? In a file? Or a string? Or something else. See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar yes it a Pandas series

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you, I will read it before I ask question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your columns are dates, use something like:

```
df.columns = [pd.to_datetime(col).day_name() for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: @PeterWood The questioner confirmed it in a comment

Comment: Thank you it works